# Git filter and sed fight over `\$`

Tags: git, sed, quoting

I am trying to write a `git` filter using `sed`

```
[filter "revisioner"]
        smudge = sed -e "s/\\\$Revision\\\$/\$Revision: $(GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core/ git describe --tag svn)\$/g"
        clean = sed -e "s/\\\$Revision: [^$]*\\\$/\$Revision\$/g"
```

For `sed` to do the correct thing it wants to have an odd number of `\` to escape the `$`, however `git` complains about an odd number of `\` with:

> ```
> fatal: bad config line 2 in file .git/../.gitconfig
> ```

I don't really want to move my `sed` script into an external command because it is yet an other moving part my users need to setup on their system, before using my repository.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to double every backslash character, wehn you put it into .gitconfig? It seems likely that you need one level of escaping for .gitconfig and one for the sed call.

Comment: I have tried any number of permutations, both with double and single quotes and a mix of them, with any number of `/`s. The results were either an error message as shown above, or nothing (my guess no match by `sed`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting escape parsing right is often a challenge, as you have to think about each program that will parse the command, and you have to think about them in order.

torek's answer has outlined the basic reasoning that applies to your case.  I will add the following, because I think the end result is a bit more readable:

First, to get the underlying sed script to work at the command line - converting, in my test, `$HI$` to `$Hello, World$` - I used

```
sed -e 's/\$HI\$/$Hello World$/g'
```

The *single-quotes* prevent bash from messing with the escapes, so `sed` sees `\$` and matches a literal `$`.  Note that the output pattern doesn't require this escaping.

Then to put this in the `.git/config` file, double each backslash, giving

```
clean = sed -e 's/\\$HI\\$/$Hello World$/g'
```

This works in my tests; if it doesn't work for you, we may need more information to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me resolve this issue, just so I will be able to hit the next one https://stackoverflow.com/q/49667015/110488

Answer (score 4):

`sed` does not need an *odd number* of backslashes.  `sed` needs to *receive*, from whatever invokes `sed`, the two-character sequence backslash, dollar-sign.

Git itself turns two backslashes into one backslash.

The shell that Git invokes to run commands also turns two backslashes into one backslash, whenever it's lexically scanning through text that is not contained inside single quotes.

Therefore, if you start with *four* backslashes:

```
\\\\$
```

Git will turn each pair into *two* backslashes:

```
\\$
```

and the shell will then turn the pair of backslashes into one backslash:

```
\$
```

after which `sed` will see one backslash followed by one dollar sign.

Note that you must do this doubling at each point at which backslashes get interpreted.  If there were one more level of interpretation applied you would need *eight* backslashes.  This kind of thing gets ugly fast which is why people move these into additional scripts.  If you provide your script as a committed file within the repository, that might be a lot easier to deal with...